# How to store localstorage items to Array jquery

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I was searching answers for this problem but I didn't find anything, my question is how to store `localstorage` item to array in jquery?

Any idea?

Comment: How about `var arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("item_name"))`?

Comment: It gives me `Unexpected token В in JSON at position 0`

Comment: Are you sure it is properly formed array. Can you paste the exact value that is stored in your localstorage

Comment: `Во потрага по Алјаска,Без страв,9-ти Ноември` this is the current localstorage item

Comment: What is the result you are looking for? `var arr = ['Во потрага по Алјаска', 'Без страв', '9-ти Ноември']`?

Comment: This is the format that I have in the localstorage and i don't know how to get every substring from the localstorage and that's why I want to store that first in the array and then loop the array...

Answer (score 0):

Localstorage always stores the value in the form of string. So, to use it as a variable you will have to convert it to JSON. Also note that localstorage can store a max of **5MB** (give or take)
Eg

```
//to store
var MY_ARRAY= 'my_array';
var arr=[1,2,3,4,5];
//store
window.localStorage.setItem(MY_ARRAY, JSON.stringify(arr));
//get
arr=JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(MY_ARRAY));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you are looking for:

```
var item = 'Во потрага по Алјаска,Без страв,9-ти Ноември';

localStorage.setItem("item_name", item);

var arr = localStorage.getItem("item_name").split(",");

console.log(arr); // ["Во потрага по Алјаска", "Без страв", "9-ти Ноември"]
```